# Changing CSS with javascript using getElementById

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an element as such:

```
<div id="admin">
```

Which has style of:

```
display: none;
```

Now, I'm trying to change that display on button press by defining and calling

```
var admin = document.getElementById('admin');
admin.style.display = "block";
```

This works just fine. When I change `admin` in both HTML and JS to something like `admin-panel` (like below), it breaks and throws me an error `admin is not defined(…)`.

```
<div id="admin-panel">
var admin = document.getElementById('admin-panel');
admin.style.display = "block";
```

Could anyone help me figure out why it works in the first instance but not the second?

**EDIT**

It seems to be working when place `var admin = document.getElementById('admin-panel');` inside the `show` and `hide` functions. Is this because the variable is not within their scope in the code below?

```
var adminView = {
  init : function() {
    var admin = document.getElementById('admin-panel');
    this.adminBtn = document.getElementById('admin-toggle');
    this.adminCancel = document.getElementById('admin-cancel');
    this.adminSave = document.getElementById('admin-save');

    this.adminCatName = document.getElementById('admin-cat-name');
    this.adminCatUrl = document.getElementById('admin-cat-url');
    this.adminCatClicks = document.getElementById('admin-cat-clicks');

    this.adminBtn.addEventListener('click', function(){
      catController.adminDisplay();
    });

    this.render();
  },

  render: function() {
    var currentCat = catController.getCurrentCat();
    this.adminCatName.value = currentCat.name;
    this.adminCatClicks.value = currentCat.clickCount;
    this.adminCatUrl.value = currentCat.img;
  },

  show: function() {
    admin.style.display = "block";
  },

  hide: function() {
    admin.style.display = "none";
  }

};
```

Comment: That should work just fine. What else did you change?

Comment: Please create a jsfiddle replicating the issue.

Comment: The code provided is working. The problem is somewhere else. Try to recreate the issue

Comment: If your code breaks at that point there will almost certainly be an error reported in your JavaScript console; what is the reported error?

Comment: May be you should share complete code, or better fiddle. Chunks of code will work.

Comment: Added a more complete code sample. Hope that helps.

Comment: How you are calling functions ? please share that code also ? you need to pass `admin` variable to the functions (`show` and `hide`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `var` from `admin` variable to make it global access .

Comment: That did the trick. Thank you!

Comment: Using **global** variables such that are **EVIL**. Don't do that.

Comment: @dashtinejad Any recommendations on how to resolve it without doing that?

Comment: @PaulVO see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40262313/3971911) below.

Comment: @dashtinejad :  I just gave the hint to resolve the issue. And everybody is free to make his own way to do this. I know you also took hint from my answer and edit your reply. I request to SO to accept his answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is because your `admin` variable isn't accessible inside your other methods. Save it as a property, and access it with `this`:

```js
var adminView = {
  init : function() {
    this.admin = document.getElementById('admin-panel');
  },

  show: function() {
    this.admin.style.display = "block";
  },

  hide: function() {
    this.admin.style.display = "none";
  }

};

adminView.init();
adminView.show();
```

```css
#admin-panel { display: none; }
```

```html
<div id="admin-panel">Hello Admin</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It works fine

```
<div id="admin-panel">
</div>

<script>
    var admin = document.getElementById('admin-panel');
    admin.style.display = "block";
</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/uzdn6ydj/

Can we get the entire code ? I think there is problem with the range of the variable

Answer (score 0):

Try It

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<button onclick="Show()" >Show</button>
<button onclick="Hide()" >Hide</button>
<div id="admin-panel" style="display:none;">
test
</div>
<p>Thank you</p>
<script>
function Show()
{
document.getElementById('admin-panel').style.display="block";
}
function Hide()
{
document.getElementById('admin-panel').style.display="none";
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```